# Linq select distinct values with comparison

Tags: linq

I have a list of objects. E.g. `List<coin>` where they contain a string(denom) and int(year).
If the list contains:

```
"Quarter", 1954
"Quarter", 1990
"Penny", 1925  
"Nickel", 1900 
"Nickel", 2000
```

How can I get a resultant list where it contains the unique values with just the most recent year? E.g.:

```
"Quarter", 1990
"Penny", 1925
"Nickel", 2000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by grouping by name, then either ordering and taking the first result, or by using something like `MaxBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.code.google.com):

```
var query = coins.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                 .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.Year));
```

or

```
var query = coins.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                 .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year).First());
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I used your second answer. While I understand the basic sql concepts, where could I find info on how this works? E.g. the .Select statement and how it references x.Year in its .OrderBy?

Comment: @tim: Each element in the result of `GroupBy` is a group of coins with the same name. If you sort each group by its year (descending), then the first entry in the sorted sequence is the latest coin of that name.

Comment: I get the concepts(only) of grouping and selecting the top value after an orderby, like in sql. It is the linq clauses that is confusing. So the GroupBy produces a set where they are grouped but I am a little lost on how OrderByDescending clause has a concrete reference to the current set.

Comment: @tim: GroupBy produces a *sequence* of groups. The Select acts on each element - i.e. each group. The OrderBy is *within* the select.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `group by` like:

```
 var query = from coin in myList
        group coin by coin.Name into grouped
        select new
        {
            Name = grouped.Key
            Year = grouped.Max(x => x.Year) 
        };
```

For another sample like this, check out "max - grouped" in the 101 Linq examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#maxGrouped

Comment: I didn't type as quickly as JonSkeet either :)

Comment: Yes, Jon outtypes us all. However, I like our answer better, much more intend revealing :-)

Comment: @Steven: On the other hand, this only works because you've only got the name and the year - if there were another property which *wasn't* involved in either the grouping or the ordering, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var coins = new Coin[] { ... };

var recentCoins =
    from coin in coins
    group coin by coin.Denom into g
    select new
    {
        Denom = g.Key, 
        MostRecentYear = g.Max(c => c.Year)
    };
```